# Why aren't product series studied as much as summation series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, soft-question

I know this is a bit of a naïve question, but why do summation series generally get more attention than product series?

There isn't even a Wikipedia page on finite product series.

Is there a higher skill cap to grasp them, or are they just generally less useful?

From the looks of it, product series can be used in integration, and some converge; so I'm assuming they can be used to describe certain spaces. So do product series make any area of calculus easier than using summation series? How about the structure on spaces they describe through convergence, can those spaces be described by the convergence of summation series instead?

Comment: Infinite products *are* studied; sometimes they are introduced in complex analysis courses.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product

Comment: I guess it's only a series technically if its infinite. There's very little on finite products of sequences. Compare the amount of material with both https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics), and they seem much less popular.

Comment: There is a lot of theory about infinite products. However, a lot of it reduces to the theory of infinite sums (i.e., series), by taking logarithms.